# Class will not log to a file with log4net

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I've got a MVC based C# Windows Forms application. I've got the following configuration in the app.config file:

```
<log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="LogConsoleAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
    </root>
   <appender name="LogConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="QAC.Source.Services.Log.LogPatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date    %level    [Thread: #%thread]    %message              [%logger -&gt; %M]%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="logs/QAC_"/>
      <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss'.log'"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
      <appendToFile value="false"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="50"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <layout type="QAC.Source.Services.Log.LogPatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date    %level    [Thread: #%thread]    %message              [%logger -&gt; %M]%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
```

In the main method, in the first lin, I call `private static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);` and after that I initialize my main service:

```
mainService = MainFactory.getMainServiceInstance();
```

And there is the problem. All log outputs in the main method are logged successfully to the file and console, also of other services (underlying services from MainService). The only class which is not logged is the MainService. The curiosity at this is, that the logging for this class starts after some time. I don't use any filter. I've turned on the log4net debugging:

```
<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
```

, but there is no error at least. So I think, that the initialization goes through. Also if I log before I initialize the MainService, it also logs to console and file. Just this class will not log.

Any help would be very nice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. I am using a custom LogPatternLayout which tries also to initialize the MainService and so the MainService is initialized before the LogPatternLayout could be read and initialized into the Logger. Therefore logging takes place after the initialization of the MainService.